# Prove that if $n = \sum_{i=1}^n |y|^i =|\sum_{i=1}^n y^i|$ for a complex number y with $|y|\leq 1$, then $y=1$.

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, summation

> Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+.$ Prove or disprove that if $\sum_{j=1}^n |y|^j =|\sum_{j=1}^n y^j|$ for a complex number y with $|y|\leq 1$, then $y=1$. Does the statement follow if we assume $n = \sum_{j=1}^n |y|^j = |\sum_{j=1}^n y^j|$?

I think the statement follows if we assume
$$n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{|y|^i} =\left|\sum_{i=1}^n y^i\right|.$$

If $|y| < 1$, then $|y|^i < 1$ for all $i$, so $\sum_{i=1}^n |y|^i < n$. I need to figure out under which conditions we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{|y|^i} > \left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}{y^i}\right|.$$

Assuming $|y| = 1$, we can write $y=e^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$. Then assuming $y\neq 1,$ we have
$$\left|{\sum_{j=1}^{n}{y^j}}\right| = \left|{\frac{e^{i(n+1)\theta}-e^{i\theta}}{e^{i\theta}-1}}\right|.$$
If $\theta$ were a rational multiple of $\pi$ with denominator $n$, this would be equal to $0$, but that may not be the case.

Comment: Hint: Use the [Triangle inequality](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Triangle_Inequality/Complex_Numbers)

Comment: Don't use $i$ as an index for questions dealing with complex numbers :)